# How can I get Python to use 1 line at a time for checking a URL?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm trying to create a python script to check data on client's websites for errors, I basically want to use a txt file with the necessary end of URL's and have the script test one line at a time.

This is the snippet from my script:

```
with open('numbers.txt') as numbers:
    for index, line in enumerate(numbers)

def urlnumber():
    number = numbers
    url = "http://www.url.com/" + number
    print ("Processing: "+url)
    result = checkErr(url)
    print(result)
```

For reference numbers.txt contains:

```
One
Two
Three
Four
Five
```

And I'm trying to make the script check "url.com/one" then "url.com/two" and so on.

If this question has been asked before, please point me in that direction, I have had a look at some similar questions, but the answers did not help me!

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: please could you add tabulation in your code so it matches what you can see in your own editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('numbers.txt') as f:
    # Read file and split them into a list called `numbers`
    numbers = f.read().splitlines()

for number in numbers:
    url = "http://www.url.com/" + number
    print ("Processing: "+url)
    result = checkErr(url)
    print(result)
```

I guess this does a cleaner job. I'd recommend you clean up the code inside the `for` loop though.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this worked, I guess I need to dedicate a couple hours a day reading the python docs before progressing further.

Comment: Because you are a fresh python users I also would recommend to use the `pathlib` package when handling with files. `p = pathlib.Path('numbers.txt'); with p.open() as f:`

Answer (score 1):

Python is a dynamically strongly typed language. So it won't convert an integer to a string when you try to concatenate them.

You have to either use string interpolation or explicitly convert it to a string.

```
for i in range(0, 10):
       url = "http://www.url.com/" + str(x)
```

Comment: But 1) when you read a file, you get strings - it doesn't convert a line that's just numerals into an int, 2) the example file contains words not numerals